# Replicated Uniforms

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, replicator, star-trek-uniforms

In the *DS9* episode ["Move Along Home"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Move_Along_Home), when Bashir realizes he doesn't have a dress uniform, why doesn't he just replicate one?

The general situation of *DS9* isn't like that of *Voyager*, and so surely power rationing could not have been the reason?

Comment: They do have plenty of power, and [don't call me Shirley](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0A5t5_O8hdA).

Comment: Haha;) get it now

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since he doesn't have access to a **Federation replicator** in his quarters (presumably Cardassian replicators don't contain the patterns for Federation uniforms) the implication is that he didn't leave himself enough time to get to a replicator station, then get changed.

Note that in the [original script](http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/410.txt), he tells Dax that his plan is to get Garak to make him one. She suggests he could **just replicate one**:

> **BASHIR:** *I'll have the clothier Garak make me a new one by tonight...*
>
> **DAX:** *I'm not sure it's appropriate to have a Cardassian tailor make your Starfleet uniform, Julian... maybe the replicator...*

Comment: Sure, but it not like you cant go 'Computer establish a uplink with the federation central replicator database, and access files on uniforms, fit for Dr Julian Bashir, ds9, and compile for cardassain replicators. done, just like any other machine language being complied into something that a device can understand.

Comment: @Pioneer - He's a Doctor, dammit, not a computer programmer.

Comment: @pioneer yea, cause printer interoperability or porting drivers is ever easy.

Comment: @cde: It would be very bizarre if there weren't some kind of standard replicator pattern exchange format common to all the major Alpha quadrant worlds — especially as every other person in the galaxy is apparently a world-class hacker/programmer.

Comment: @Lèse that doesn't even happen now. Every printer, cnc, plotter, 3d printer has different standards and it takes forever to get ports. And we have open standards like cups and postscript and everything.

Comment: Frankly, while I do see a plothole here, I would have liked the original script even less. Without claiming that Garak isn't talented as a clothier, I would not expect nowadays' policemen or soldiers to walk into a public street-side clothes store and tell the assistant: "Here's what my uniform has to look like, can you make one from scratch?" Where Starfleet personnel has no access to replicators, I'd expect Starfleet to supply uniforms produced elsewhere, centrally, instead of just leaving their poor officers with a book of sewing patterns.

Comment: @cde: I think you're confusing drivers with file formats. Yes, hardware-specific drivers have to be written in order to even use the I/O device (that's the whole purpose of drivers). But you don't need to convert a JPEG or PDF to an Epson- or Canon-specific format to print it. Likewise, when you switch CNC routers, you don't have to convert all of your CAD files. And even among most major proprietary formats or competing standards, there are simple ways to convert between them using common software.

Comment: @Lèse I forgot about that. But no, you still have to use file converters for most specialty printers. Look at consumer vinyl cutters like the cricket. And printers don't directly use jpg or anything, the app or os translates that to the appropriate raw printer format.

Comment: @cde: The Cricut can print SVG files. Commodity printers simply accept PostScript or PCL documents, and the conversion from desktop file formats is completely transparent to the user. The point is, if all these worlds are interacting with one another, engaging in trade and diplomacy, sharing spaces, exchanging culture, etc., someone's bound to come up with either a dominant standard or software for easy conversion between major formats.

Comment: When Neelix meets Tuvok in Voyager he asks if the replicator will make him a uniform like Tuvok's. Tuvok is not impressed and says no. So it appears that there are restrictions on replicating uniforms on a starship, so I don't see why Starfleet would allow it on DS9 either. Presumably they would have to upload the pattern from the Federation database to the station's Cardasian computers and this would not get approval.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté JPEG and PDF are really really simple examples compared to, say, Photoshop or Gimp files.  Those outright can't be converted safely from one to the other, because even simple things like text and gradients are handled completely differently.  Replicator patterns would be even more complex.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from @Richard's answer,  you need authorization to replicate a uniform or weapon. The replicators have Digital Rights Management (DRM) to protect the ship and individuals, or else anyone could replicate anything they could think of.

It likely is tracked as well,  because letting anyone print out as many copies as they want would be just as bad.

Comment: Drm? This means?

Comment: @Pioneer ; DRM = Digital Rights Management. Basically online copyright.