# When did Worf get a Klingon uniform?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-uniforms

I'm probably missing something, but in the episode REDEMPTION PT. 1, Worf resigns his commission to join Gowron and serve on the IKS Bortas.  He lays down his com-badge in the observation lounge, and in the next scene he's in his room packing his stuff--wearing a full grown Klingon military uniform!

AFAIK Worf never joined the KDF, so they certainly didn't give him one.  If his dad died at Khitomer, presumably he (the dad) was wearing his uniform at the time and it's got holes and disrupter burns.  I know he somehow held on to the bat'leth that was in his family for like ten generations, so I suppose it's not a stretch to think he could have inherited or obtained a uniform from a friendly Klingon family.

I think I remember on DS9 Rom had a Starfleet uniform made for Nog before he set off to the Academy.  Did Worf just replicate a cheap Earth knock-off Klingon uniform?  Maybe when he was younger and researching his culture?

I know he wore a different uniform in THE EMISSARY to talk down the T'Ong, but that was just a ruse to convince the T'Ong not to freak out.

Answer (score 6):

The most likely answer is Worf simply had a regulation klingon uniform replicated for him. From other episodes in both TNG and Voyager were shown that the crews are almost always wearing local garb when trying to hide who they are/meeting new people. They cant possibly carry all those clothes so they simply replicate them before heading out.

Answer (score 0):

The [script](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/200.txt) doesn't say. He simply goes back to his room and when we next see him (an indeterminate amount of time later), he's wearing a customised Klingon Uniform.

> INT. WORF'S QUARTERS - CLOSE ON WORF:
>
> **MOVE TO REVEAL Worf now wearing a KLINGON UNIFORM  (which should
>   incorporate his sash into the outfit).**
>
> Most of his things are already packed and sitting on his bed. He looks
>   around the room that has been his home for four years... Worf turns...
>   sees his reflection in the mirror... looks himself over with
>   curiosity... is this who he is? The door CHIMES.

Given that fact that he's (apparently) never seen himself in this sort of uniform before, it's not likely that he already had it in his possession.

Most probably he simply went to [the replimat](http://www.stardestroyer.net/wiki/images/b/b3/Replimat.jpg) and asked for one. We know that they can [make Federation uniforms](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/91745/20774) and we know that they've got [high quality scans of Klingon warriors on file](http://previously.tv/m/2016-07-25-star-trek-tng01.jpg) so it's hardly a stretch of the imagination that the ship could make him an appropriate Klingon uniform on request.