# In what way did Worf "come here in a child's uniform"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, worf

In *The Next Generation* episode "Sins of the Father", Duras says to Worf,

> "Yet you come here in a child's uniform and you bring outsiders to our great halls."

What was Worf wearing that Duras called a child's uniform?

- Something he wore as a child at Khitomer?  According to [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Worf), Worf was 6 years old at the time of the Khitomer massacre.  How would an adult Worf be able to wear such a child-sized item?
- His baldric?  Worf wears it throughout two series, and it is an adult size.  (It does, however, change color between TNG seasons 1 and 2.)
- His Starfleet uniform?  In that case, wouldn't Klingons disparage all Starfleet uniforms as a child's uniform?
- The sleeveless Klingon cloak he wears over his Starfleet uniform?  Unlikely, as other members of the High Council and Duras also wear the same garment (see picture below).

[image: Worf before the High Council]

Question regarding a later episode: [When did Worf get a Klingon uniform?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/144608/102339)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I believe it's the third option you listed -- that the Starfleet uniform is a child's uniform.  The logic is that from the Klingon point of view the ideals of Starfleet and the Federation are childish.  If Duras does not call it a "child's uniform" when worn by other Starfleet officers, it's because he doesn't have any expectations that they would be real warriors like he would of a Klingon.

Comment: Might also be that the uniform is similar to what Klingon children wear before they grow into the whole leather and metal thing the adults are into - but since we only see a couple of Klingon children in the whole ST universe (and not within an actual Klingon community from what I recall) it's hard to say.

Comment: But mostly,  the point is simply to insult Worf as not being a true Klingon warrior

Comment: It's an insult, not a literal observation.  Rather in the price-range of human culture where a man wearing a formal tuxedo is wearing a "penguin suit" or a "monkey suit".

Comment: He should just be thankful it wasn't Season 1, with the stretchy one-piece pyjama uniforms!

Answer (score 7):

It was a disparaging remark. Earlier in the episode, Kern makes insulting remarks about Worf's quarters being comfortable and how the Enterprise is "not the ship for a warrior, not the ship for a Klingon."

TNG has several more references of Klingon's making derogatory comments to Wolf and others in Star Fleet.  The first instance probably being in season one's *Heart of Glory*, when the two Klingons mock Worf a little for serving on a Starfleet vessel.

To Klingon's, serving in Star Fleet is [child's play](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/child%27s+play). Humans are thought of as weak, like a child.

Comment: Wonder if they saw and knew of Earth's history during the times of human warriors (Sparta, Troy, Rome, etc.) if they would think the same

Comment: @MissouriSpartan What's the Klingon for "What happened, dude?  You used to be cool..." xD